# Theoretical Mechanics - Lagrange - Equations of motion

Tags: physics, classical-mechanics

How do I find the equations of movement of this system? I do not know how to determine the kinetic energy "$T$" and the potential energy "$V$". Any suggestions?. I know that the Lagrangian is of the form $L = T-V$ but my question is how to determine the energies $T$ and $V$.

It is the following system:

[image]

Comment: The only potential you have here is the gravitational potential. Just chose a set of coordinates by noticing that you have only 3 degrees of freedom (why?). Then you need to find the height of the two masses to find the gravitational potential. To find the velocities just find the positions and differentiate them.

Comment: There are two generalized coordinates. $X_{m_2}$ or $X_{m_1}$ and $X_M$

Comment: You're right, my fault

Answer (score 1):

A little help

First the potential energy $V$

$$
V=h_{1}m_{1}g+h_{2}m_{2}g
$$

with the restrictions

$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
X_{m_{1}}+X_{m_{2}} & = & L_{0}\\
h_{1} & = & (L_{0}-X_{m_{2}})\sin\alpha\\
h_{2} & = & X_{m_{2}}\sin\beta
\end{array}
$$

Now concerning the velocities

$$
\frac{dX_{m_{1}}}{dt}+\frac{dX_{m_{2}}}{dt}=v_{1}+v_{2}=0,\:v_{3}=\frac{dX_{M}}{dt}
$$

Now the kinetic energy $T$

$$
T=\frac{1}{2}m_{1}\left\Vert \vec{V_{1}}\right\Vert ^{2}+\frac{1}{2}m_{2}\left\Vert \vec{V_{2}}\right\Vert ^{2}+\frac{1}{2}M\left\Vert \vec{V}_{3}\right\Vert ^{2}
$$

where

$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
\vec{V_{1}} & = & \hat{i}v_{3}-(\hat{i}\cos\alpha+\hat{j}\sin\alpha)v_{1}\\
\vec{V_{2}} & = & \hat{i}v_{3}+(\hat{i}\cos\beta-\hat{j}\sin\beta)v_{2}\\
\vec{V_{3}} & = & \hat{i}v_{3}
\end{array}
$$

$$
T = \frac{1}{2}\left(m_1v_1^2+m_2 v_2^2+(M+m_1+m_2)v_3^2-2m_1v_1v_3\cos(\alpha)+2m_2v_2v_3\cos(\beta)\right)
$$

etc.

NOTE

Here there are two generalized coordinates: $X_{m_2}$ and $X_M$ because $X_{m_1}+X_{m_2} = L_0$

Calling $\phi_1 = X_{m_2}$ and $\phi_2 = X_M$ we have

$$
V = (L_0-\phi_1)m_1g\sin(\alpha) + \phi_1m_2 g\sin(\beta)
$$

and

$$
T =  \frac{1}{2}\left(m_1\dot \phi_1^2+m_2 \dot \phi_1^2+(M+m_1+m_2)\dot \phi_2^2-2m_1 \dot \phi_1\dot\phi_2\cos(\alpha)-2m_2\dot\phi_1\dot\phi_2\cos(\beta)\right)
$$